# Bullet implementation in java game

Tags: java

I have a java game where i want to make a form of shooting that spawns three bullets at different angles. An example of the shot could be something like this:

```
 *   *
   * 
 ship
```

Where the * are representing bullets. I have an implementation that spawns one bullet in front of the ship with a certain velocity. How would it be possible to spawn another two bullets like the very bad diagram above.

Here is how i actually create the bullet infront of the ship:

```
 public void mkCannonball(){

    Vector2D shipPos = new Vector2D(direction);
    shipPos.normalise().mult(this.radius +2).add(position);
    Vector2D bulletTrajectory = new Vector2D(direction);
    bulletTrajectory.normalise().mult(Constants.BULLET_SPEED).add(velocity);
    cannonball = new Cannonball(new Vector2D(shipPos), new Vector2D(bulletTrajectory));
    SoundManager.fire();
}
```

Comment: Just use `direction` and rotate it by whatever angle you need then create another `Cannonball`. You could also call `mkCannonball` 3 times and pass the angle as a parameter but you'd probably not want to repeat all the calculations 3 times as well as play the sound 3 times.

Comment: Btw, I'd guess the bullet and velocity tags are not correct here since they apply to libraries with those names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something along these lines...

```
public void mkCannonball(){

  Vector2D shipPos = new Vector2D(direction);
  shipPos.normalise().mult(this.radius +2).add(position);

  Vector2D leftBulletTrajectory = new Vector2D(direction - 1);
  Vector2D rightBulletTrajectory = new Vector2D(direction + 1);

  leftBulletTrajectory.normalise().mult(Constants.BULLET_SPEED).add(velocity);
  rightBulletTrajectory.normalise().mult(Constants.BULLET_SPEED).add(velocity);

  leftCannonball = new Cannonball(new Vector2D(shipPos), new Vector2D(leftBulletTrajectory));
  rightCannonball = new Cannonball(new Vector2D(shipPos), new Vector2D(rightBulletTrajectory));

  SoundManager.fire();
}
```

Basically just creating two trajectories   (left and right) with modified directions. Then creating two cannonballs using those trajectories.

I think the trick will be figuring out how to modify the vector direction a couple degrees for left and right. In the code above I just used + and - 1.

Comment: This is a great solution! Though i noticed when bullets spawn at a certain ship direction, they spawn inside the ship and collide with it. Either way this implementation does work!